# Interfacing with TC5564APL-15 paralell static ram

Tags: arduino-uno, sram

I've found a Z80 processor and a TC5564APL-15 8K static ram chips, and I want to test the RAM chip, because it's really old and I'm not sure that it's not damaged. I do not have any experience with Z80's and RAM chip's, I'm not even sure that I didn't damage it while desoldering. I found [THIS](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=66630.15) forum link, where a guy wanted to use a different RAM chip, but the code looked OK and I've took it. I did some modifications:

- I only own one 74HC595, so I used that, I've connected the remaining address lines to 5V via 200Ohm resistors
- I did not use any capacitors.
- I've changed some connections.

Here's the modified code:
https://pastebin.com/9nfTQY8X
(Sorry for PB)

So it SHOULD print "0 0 0 8 / 0 0 0 8" to the serial, but it prints "0 0 0 8 / 8 8 8 8". The reason is unknown. Every other number works, I only found that specific bit not working correctly.
I'm not sure. Can my RAM chip be broken, or the circuit causes the problems?

Comment: Add a capacitor (0.1 uF at least) to the RAM chip.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Z80 and old memory chips; no Arduino involved.

Comment: The "modified code" on PasteBin has been deleted so there is definitely no way to answer this question as it stands.